# In morris.bar chart all label is not showing But when I Zoom in all Labels are showing properly

Tags: javascript, morris.js

[image: Bar Chart Screenshot]In Morris.js Bar chart all labels are not showing properly

But in big screen it shows all labels properly.It has 12 labels but it's not showing all labels.

```
Morris.Bar({
        element: 'morris-bar-chart',
        barGap:4,
        barSizeRatio:0.55,
        data: [

            <?php for($i=0;$i<12;$i++)
            {
                echo "{y: '";
                echo $barchart1[$i]->month;
                echo "', a: ";
                echo $barchart1[$i]->totalamount; 
                echo ", b:";
                echo ($barchart2[$i]->totalamount) ? $barchart2[$i]->totalamount : "0";
                echo "}";

                if($i!=11)
                {
                  echo ",\n";
                }
            }
                ?>
           ],
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
        labels: ['Invoice Amount', 'Received Amount'],
        barColors: ['#55ce63', '#03a9f3'],
        hideHover: 'auto',
        gridLineColor: '#eef0f2',
        resize: true
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because Morris chart applies by default a left and right margin to labels on X-axis. This is to avoid that labels are too close to each other. You can change it through the option `xLabelMargin` (default value is 50, you can try with 10 per example).